# UITextField not updating when entering the keyboard keys

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When I tap on this `UITextField`mentioned on screen below, a numpad keyboard appears, the problem is that when I start tap on number, my `UITextField` do not update, stay with no number, only `placeholder`.

[image]

What I need to do?

Thanks

ADDING CODE!

```
@IBOutlet weak var salarioTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()

{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateView()

    salarioTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool

{

    if textField == feriasTextField
    {
        feriasTextField.inputView = feriasPicker
    }

    else if textField == salarioTextField
    {
        salarioTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    }

    else if textField == inicioTextField
    {
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        datePicker.date = inicioDate
    }
    else if textField == motivoTextField
    {
        motivoTextField.inputView = motivoPicker
    }
    else
    {
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        datePicker.date = fimDate
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    let scrollSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    backgroundScrollView.contentSize = scrollSize
    activeTextField = textField
    activeTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    backgroundScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 800)
    backgroundScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
}
```

Please ignore the others `UITextField`.

Comment: Have you set a delegate for the textField?

Comment: Add the code that you have so far

Comment: Yes, I have set delegate.

Comment: Please share code you used to set up the text field. Also share code for the text field delegate methods you implemented.

Comment: I added some parts of my code.

Comment: @fluidsonic Any idea about what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what was happening.

I was returning false to the method below.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return true;

}
```

Just changed it to true and it's working.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled user interaction for the field.

If you implement the delegate method `textViewDidBeginEditing`, you can put a breakpoint or a `print` statement here to see if it triggers.

You can try calling `becomeFirstResponder` on the field.

Comment: I have implemented the delegate method, when I tap on this `UITextField`, it becomes the responder ad the keyboard appears, but don't work.

Comment: And you are sure user interaction is enabled for this field?